# Single-table-inheritance type in mountable Rails::Engine doesn't contain namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

I'm creating a mountable Rails engine (3.2.x) in which there's a single-table inheritance model:

```
module Geo
  class Location < ActiveRecord::Base; end
end

module Geo
  class Country < Location; end
end
```

However, when saving a `Location`, the `type` field contains `Country`, rather than `Geo::Country` ...which is fine by me...except that I'll get this error after including the Engine in another gem.

> ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'Country'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Geo::Location.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.

What's the best way around this? Is it possible to keep the non-namespaced type (`Country` rather than `Geo::Country)? Or do I have to tell my Geo::Location model to explicitly use the namespace?

Comment: looks like you need the namespace in the type column as you say. That is how rails does it automatically when you do Country.new.type you get "Geo::Country"